# Configure make command for fortran in Geany

Tags: makefile, fortran, gfortran, geany

sorry if it's a simple question, I'm a bit of a rookie and couldn't find the answer online.

I have a program in Fortran with a makefile that I need to run. I am able to run it through the terminal, by using mingw32-make command, but I'd like to do be able to do it through Geany as well.

When I just try to do it by pressing Make in Geany, nothing happens and a message at the bottom of the screen says *Process failed (The system cannot find the file specified).* From what I gather, I need to configure a new make command in Geany through Set build commands and that might solve the problem, but this is where I am lost. What exactly do I need to type in there? Do I need to direct it to mingw32-make? How do I do that?

[This is what my Set Build commands window looks like now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60nJL.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Do compile, build and run work?

Comment: Compile works on the individual files. I'm not sure how to build and run on the group of files in Geany

Answer (score 0):

Two options

1. In your fortran bin directory copy mingw32_make.exe to make.exe.
2. In geany, change make to mingw32_make

The make in geany should then work.

Comment: thank you, I changed make in Geany and it worked. Such a simple solution, a bit embarrassed I didn't think of it myself :D